# Изменение в таблице базы данных mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, веб-программирование

Есть таблица Users в безе данных app

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как изменить статус на 1 для cherry если я знаю его id(2) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простой [`UPDATE` запрос](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) поможет Вам:

```
UPDATE 
    Users
SET 
    status = 1
WHERE
    id = 2
```